# How to show value which get from database in select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-mobile

I would like to show value in select option which value was query from database. And this value should be use in another functions, not to show only.

This is html script with JQM.

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-field-contain">
    <label>Priority : </label>
    <select name="priority" id="idPriority">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="High">High (3days)</option>
        <option value="Low">Low (5days)</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

This is jQuery script.

```
function functionSuccess(data){
    var eachrow = JSON.parse(data);
    $('#idPriority').val(eachrow[0].logPriority);    //This line is not work
}
```

PS.I use Ajax and PHP to get data from database. And I'm sure that data come already because I have tested to show value in input textbox and no problems.

PS.I don't use append() because it cannot use to define value. It can show data only.

Comment: Add response string `data`

Comment: I don't think the problem is data. I have tested by fixed value like $('#idPriority').val("Test"); but it still doesn't show the value at select option.

Answer (score 0):

You can set only those value to dropdown which are already in option so you can set `""`, `High` and `Low` value only. If you tried to set any other value than these E.g `Test` then it will not work.

```js
var myResponse = [{"logPriority":"High"}];
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#idPriority').val(myResponse[0].logPriority);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-field-contain">
    <label>Priority : </label>
    <select name="priority" id="idPriority">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="High">High (3days)</option>
        <option value="Low">Low (5days)</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tested like your suggestion but it does not work, show nothing and no error.

Comment: Can you add response data as I asked earlier...?

Comment: I'm new with this. Could you give me how to do that?
 I have only check console.log(data) and it shows [{"logPriority":"High"}]

Comment: Check the updated answer...and if you response is same as listed above then comment `var eachrow = JSON.parse(data);` and replace `eachrow[0].logPriority` with `data[0].logPriority`

Comment: I test with your updated answer but still not show. For value of these two, eachrow[0].logType > High, data[0].logPriority > Undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by using localStorage and append() together.

For HTML script, I have added class to select tag.

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-field-contain">
    <label>Priority : </label>
    <select name="priority" id="idPriority" class="classPriority">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="High">High (3days)</option>
        <option value="Low">Low (5days)</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

For jQuery script

```
function functionSuccess(data){
    var eachrow = JSON.parse(data);
    $('.classPriority').append(eachrow[0].logPriority);    //show value
    localStorage.setItem("SelectPriority",eachrow[0].logPriority);    //Keep value
}
```

And example to get value in another function.

```
function examplePullValue() {
    alert(localStorage.getItem("SelectPriority"));    //get value
    localStorage.removeItem("SelectPriority");    //remove value
}
```